# How to call a Python Google Cloud Function from React Native? (Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I need to call a Python Google Cloud Function from a React Native/Expo app, which uses Nodejs (Javascript as the language) and get the value that it returns.

I can't find any guide on how to do this, I only find Firebase JS/TS Functions guides.

The function requires data so I'll need to send, let's say, a list. Is this possible without any special package?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally cloud functions, regardless of Python or Node can be set up as endpoints, but not as React hosts, so to speak.

This might be useful: https://www.oreilly.com/learning/serverless-on-google-with-cloud-functions-and-react